# antd design - Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected

Tags: reactjs, antd, snowpack

I am getting this React error when running in dev mode with Snowpack

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

This import is where the error is comming from.

```
import { Button } from "antd"
```

This is the dependencies you need to know about.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.5.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@snowpack/app-scripts-react": "^1.8.3",
    "snowpack": "^2.7.6"
  }
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

I have tried so far these imports without luck.

```
import { Button } from "antd/lib/button"
```

and

```
import Button from "antd/lib/button"
```

Comment: The warning is not about import statement. Post the code with line that throws this warning. Your import is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Antd Button accepts a prop `type` as a string, but it seems you are passing an object instead. Maybe you need to check again how you implemented your button.

Answer (score 0):

Antd Button accepts one of 5 STRING options : ["default", "primary", "dashed", "text", "link"](https://ant.design/components/button/#components-button-demo-basic). You are trying to pass an object instead.

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
```

Also, this works just fine. Using VScode would help with importing by simply type  and VSCode will guide you to how to import the desired component